# CSS animation stutters in Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, animation

On our corporate login pages, I'm trying to produce a "Ken Burns" effect. Given a series of random images, an image will fade and zoom in (starting from opacity: 0), then quickly fade and zoom out (again, to opacity: 0), to be replaced immediately by another image with the same animation. The effect is set to last 10 seconds and loop infinitely.

The effect works perfectly in Firefox; in Chrome however, the randomizing of images gets out of sync with the CSS animation, and the old image reappears for a split second after fading out before it is replaced with the new image. (I'd post a video screen capture, but I don't want to give away the corporate identity.) What could be causing this in Chrome, and how could it be fixed?

```js
var numOfImages = 5;
    
if (window.screen.availWidth >= 1250) {
    // Preloading images
    if (!img1) {
        var img1 = new Image();
        img1.src = "/_images/background/1.lowsrc.jpg";
    }
    if (!img2) {
        var img2 = new Image();
        img2.src = "/_images/background/2.lowsrc.jpg";
    }
    if (!img3) {
        var img3 = new Image();
        img3.src = "/_images/background/3.lowsrc.jpg";
    }
    if (!img4) {
        var img4 = new Image();
        img4.src = "/_images/background/4.lowsrc.jpg";
    }
    if (!img5) {
        var img5 = new Image();
        img5.src = "/_images/background/5.lowsrc.jpg";
    }
}

var getRandom = function () {
    var img = document.getElementById('autoImg');
    var r = Math.random();
    r = r * numOfImages;
    r = Math.ceil(r);
    img.src = '/_images/background/' + r + '.lowsrc.jpg';
}

var initAnimation = function () {
    if (window.innerWidth == 1920) {
        getRandom();
        setInterval(getRandom, 10000);
    } else {
        getRandom();
    }
}

window.onload = initAnimation;
```

```css
@keyframes kb2 {
    0% {
        opacity: 0.01;
        filter: blur(0.5rem);
    }

    10% {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    50% {
        filter: blur(0);
    }

    80% {
        transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1) translate3d( calc(-0.2 * (1400px - (100% - 480px)) / 2), calc(-0.6 * (1495px - 100vh) / 2), 0 );
        animation-timing-function: ease-in;
        opacity: 1;
    }

    95% {
        transform: scale3d(1.25, 1.25, 1.25) translate3d(-72px, -100px, 0);
        animation-timing-function: ease-out;
        opacity: 0.01;
        filter: blur(0);
    }
    100% {
        transform: scale3d(1.25, 1.25, 1.25) translate3d(-72px, -100px, 0);
        animation-timing-function: ease-out;
        opacity: 0;
        filter: blur(0);
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1920px) and (max-height: 1495px) {
    #HeroUnit img {
        animation: kb2 10s infinite;
        transform: translate3d(0, calc(-0.7 * (1495px - 100vh) / 2), 0);
    }
}
```

```html
<section id="HeroUnit">
    <img id="autoImg" />
    <p><span>Corporate</span><br /><span>Slogan</span></p>
</section>
```

Thanks in advance for any/all help!

Answer (score 0):

CSS timing is not accurate at all and you can't trust it for ms perfect animations. Try using callback functions in JS. Or use one of the many animation libraries for JS.